# how to write an iPhone backend?

Tags: iphone, json, backend

Does anyone knows of tutorial on how to write a backend in any 
language that can communicate with an iPhone using JSON?

Thanks.

Comment: any webservice can be accesed from an iphone.. you need to look into what kind of technology you want to use first i would say...

Comment: Isn't this a "How do you write a server?" question?  I think we need a slightly more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something on an iPhone that can access/parse JSON look into using SBJson. It is pretty lightweight and has been working great for the applications that I have written. It adds a simple extension to NSString, where you can just do the following

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:someURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [jsonString jsonValue];
```

Is this what you want?